# How to optimize these two functions into clean code (No jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, dom, modal-dialog, css-transitions

I have this very "not clean" code where I open a modal with an animation:

```js
const modal = document.getElementById("modal");
const modalDarkBackground = document.getElementById("modalDarkBackground");

document.getElementById("openModal").onclick = function() {
  modal.style.opacity = "1";
  modal.style.zIndex = "9999";
  modal.style.transform = "translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1)";
  modalDarkBackground.style.zIndex = "9998";
  modalDarkBackground.style.opacity = "1";
}

document.getElementById("closeModal").onclick = function() {
  modal.style.transform = "translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.1)";

  setTimeout(function() {
    modal.style.opacity = "0";
    modal.style.zIndex = "-1";
    modal.style.transform = "translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0)";
    modalDarkBackground.style.zIndex = "-1";
    modalDarkBackground.style.opacity = "0";
  }, 500);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

#modalDarkBackground {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  transition: all 0.5s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

#modal {
  width: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
  background: #fff;
}
#modal h1 {
  background: #E6E6E6;
  color: #ff0C0C;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
}
#modal p {
  min-height: 70px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  color: #ff0C0C;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 15px;
}
#modal button {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  background: #EDB44C;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto 0.5em auto;
  border: 1px solid #BEBEBE;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<button id="openModal">
  Open Modal
</button>

<div id="modalDarkBackground"></div>
<div id="modal">
  <h1>Error</h1>

  <p id="modalContent">
    You do not seem to have an Internet connection.
    Please check your connection.
  </p>

  <button id="closeModal">
    OK
  </button>
</div>
```

I noticed that my JavaScript code is very bad with inline styles and way too long. Is there a way to optimize this JavaScript code with e.g. AddClass and maybe make a single function out of it? Sorry, I am a JavaScript newbie

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using something like [alert()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert)? It's better for accessibility.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of hard-wiring the effected DOM nodes with their intended behavior, and instead of CSS-data baked into the JavaScript code as well, one could give a ***component (DOM)*** and ***module (JavaScript)*** based approach more than just a single thought.

*On top one leaves the animation behavior entirely to the CSS by targeting this **behavior via a common set of css class names** which will be used by the JavaScript logic.*

Of cause one has to start with a more generic and better structured markup. Especially the nesting is crucial for how one can target the layout rules, and even more, how one can achieve a fine grained targeting of element specific css transformations.

Thus, the OP's original CSS got slightly reassembled according to the new markup.

The OP might also notice the class name specific rules for/under `active`, `before-deactivation` and `deactivating` which each target a **specific state of a *just or still* raised modal** component and which are customizable via related `data-*` attributes at every `modal` component's root node.

The idea behind a `modals`-module is convenience and flexibility. The module internally stores `modal` items by each item's corresponding element-node.

The module features just two methods `get` and `initialize`. The latter identifies all `modal` related element-nodes by their specific `data-component-modal` attribute and creates a node specific `modal`-item.

Thus every *modal related* element-node can be used by the module's `get` method, either to retrieve an already existing `modal`-item, or to create, store and get a new element-node specific `modal`-item.

Each item owns exactly two methods `activate` and `deactivate` which literally trigger a behavior according to its naming/wording.

Thus the component approach allows the usage of more than just one *modal component* within one and the same document. It allows other program logic or components to retrieve and use `modal`-items individually by their element-node reference and e.g. trigger *modal behavior* like raising/opening (`activate`) or closing (`deactivate`) the modal related element-node.

The implementation of the final executable snippet's `main` function does demonstrate the just said exemplarily ...

```
function main() {
  modals.initialize();

  document
    .querySelectorAll('[data-activate-modal]')
    .forEach(triggerNode => document
      .querySelectorAll(triggerNode.dataset.activateModal)
      .forEach(componentNode => triggerNode
        .addEventListener('click', modals.get(componentNode).activate)
      )
    );
}
```

... `modals` does get initialized first. Then there are some buttons which we want to be triggers for raising different modals. Such a button/trigger gets identified by its `data-activate-modal` attribute. And the value of the latter will be used as element-query for the targeted modal. For instance a button like ...

```
<button data-activate-modal='#warningModal'>
  Open Warning Modal
</button>
```

... does target any modal which gets queried by `'#warningModal'` which of cause for the example is just a sole modal component due to the used `id` based selector.

Finally any triggering element is going to handle any of its targeted `modal`-items by `activate`-ing each related item on such a trigger's e.g. `click` event.

But of cause there are many more options left with the approach of ***storing and retrieving modal items*** via their related element-node references.

```js
// `modals` module.
const modals = (function () {

  function getSafeInteger(value) {
    value = parseInt(value, 10);
    return Number.isSafeInteger(value) ? value : 0;
  }

  function activateBoundModalTarget() {
    this.classList.add('active');
  }
  function deactivateBoundModalTarget() {
    const modalNode = this;
    let {
      deactivationDuration: delayDefault,
      deactivationDelay: delayBefore,
    } = modalNode.dataset;

    delayDefault = getSafeInteger(delayDefault);
    delayBefore = getSafeInteger(delayBefore);

    modalNode.classList.add('before-deactivation', 'deactivating');

    setTimeout(() => {
      modalNode.classList.remove('active', 'before-deactivation');

      setTimeout(() =>
        modalNode.classList.remove('deactivating'), delayDefault
      );
    }, delayBefore);
  }

  // `modal` item/type factory
  function createModal(rootNode) {
    const activate = activateBoundModalTarget.bind(rootNode);
    const deactivate = deactivateBoundModalTarget.bind(rootNode);
    rootNode
      .querySelectorAll('[data-trigger-inactive]')
      .forEach(triggerNode => triggerNode
        .addEventListener('click', deactivate)
      );
    return {
      rootNode,
      activate,
      deactivate
    }
  }
  const storage = new WeakMap;

  function getModal(rootNode) {
    let modal = storage.get(rootNode);
    if (
      !modal &&
      (rootNode instanceof HTMLElement) &&
      rootNode.hasAttribute('data-component-modal')
    ) {
      if (modal = createModal(rootNode)) {

        storage.set(rootNode, modal);
      }
    }
    return modal ?? null;
  }

  function initialize() {
    document
      .querySelectorAll('[data-component-modal]')
      .forEach(getModal);
  }

  // export module.
  return {
    get: getModal,
    initialize,
  };
}());


function main() {
  modals.initialize();

  document
    .querySelectorAll('[data-activate-modal]')
    .forEach(triggerNode => document
      .querySelectorAll(triggerNode.dataset.activateModal)
      .forEach(componentNode => triggerNode
        .addEventListener('click', modals.get(componentNode).activate)
      )
    );
}
main();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

[data-component-modal] {
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
[data-component-modal] .background {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.9);
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
[data-component-modal] .content {
  zoom: .8;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}

[data-component-modal].deactivating,
[data-component-modal].active {
  z-index: 99;
}
[data-component-modal].active .background,
[data-component-modal].active .content {
  opacity: 1;
}
[data-component-modal].active.before-deactivation .content {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.1);
}

[data-component-modal].error .background {
  background: rgba(255, 192, 192, 0.9);
}

[data-component-modal] .content h1 {
  background: #E6E6E6;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
}
[data-component-modal] .content p {
  min-height: 70px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 15px;
}
[data-component-modal].error .content h1,
[data-component-modal].error .content p {
  color: #ff0C0C;
}
[data-component-modal] .content button {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  background: #EDB44C;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto 0.5em auto;
  border: 1px solid #BEBEBE;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<button data-activate-modal='#errorModal'>
  Open Error Modal
</button>
<button data-activate-modal='#warningModal'>
  Open Warning Modal
</button>
<button data-activate-modal='#errorModal'>
  Open Error Modal
</button>
<button data-activate-modal='#warningModal'>
  Open Warning Modal
</button>

<div
  data-component-modal
  data-deactivation-duration='500'
  id="errorModal"
  class="error"
  >
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Error</h1>

    <p id="modalContent">
      You do not seem to have an Internet connection.
      Please check your connection.
    </p>

    <button data-trigger-inactive>
      OK
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="background"></div>
</div>

<div
  data-component-modal
  data-deactivation-duration='500'
  data-deactivation-delay='500'
  id="warningModal"
  >
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Warning</h1>

    <p id="modalContent">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </p>

    <button data-trigger-inactive>
      OK
    </button>
    <button data-trigger-inactive>
      close
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="background"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can describe transition in css classes and add/remove them to show/hide the modal

```js
const modal = document.getElementById("modal");
const modalDarkBackground = document.getElementById("modalDarkBackground");

const show = () => {
    modal.classList.add('show');
    modalDarkBackground.classList.add('show');
};

const hide = () => {
    modal.classList.add('prepare-hide');
    setTimeout(function() {
        modal.classList.remove('prepare-hide');
        modal.classList.remove('show');
        modalDarkBackground.classList.remove('show');
    }, 500);
};

modalDarkBackground.onclick = hide;

document.getElementById("openModal").onclick = show;

document.getElementById("closeModal").onclick = hide;
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

#modalDarkBackground {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transition: all 0.5s;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

#modal {
    width: 300px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    opacity: 0;
    background: #fff;
}

#modal h1 {
    background: #E6E6E6;
    color: #ff0C0C;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 0.5em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
}

#modal p {
    min-height: 70px;
    padding: 0.5em;
    color: #ff0C0C;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 15px;
}

#modal button {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    background: #EDB44C;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto 0.5em auto;
    border: 1px solid #BEBEBE;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

#modalDarkBackground.show {
    z-index: 9998;
    opacity: 1;
}

#modal.show {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 9999;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}

#modal.prepare-hide {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<button id="openModal">
Open Modal
</button>


<div id="modalDarkBackground"></div>
<div id="modal">
<h1>Error</h1>

<p id="modalContent">
    You do not seem to have an Internet connection. Please check your connection.
</p>

<button id="closeModal">
    OK
</button>

</div>
```

Comment: The close animation with the dark background isn't really working well

Comment: @GucciBananaKing99 I have not changed the properties set by the author, I only describe them using css

Comment: @GucciBananaKing99 added a click handler to the background

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the JS code using style classes.

And I moved styles from JS to a style block.

Now the JS looks better.

```js
const modal = document.getElementById('modal');
const modalDarkBackground = document.getElementById('modalDarkBackground');

document.getElementById('openModal').onclick = function() {
  modal
    .classList.add('openModal');
  modalDarkBackground
    .classList.add('modalDarkBackgroundOpen');
}

document.getElementById('closeModal').onclick = function() {
  modal
    .classList.add('transformScale');

  setTimeout(function() {
    modal
      .classList.replace('openModal', 'closeModal');
    modalDarkBackground
      .classList.replace('modalDarkBackgroundOpen', 'modalDarkBackgroundClose');
  }, 500);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

#modalDarkBackground {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  transition: all 0.5s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

#modal {
  width: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
  background: #fff;
}
#modal h1 {
  background: #E6E6E6;
  color: #ff0C0C;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
}
#modal p {
  min-height: 70px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  color: #ff0C0C;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 15px;
}
#modal button {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  background: #EDB44C;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto 0.5em auto;
  border: 1px solid #BEBEBE;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#modal.openModal {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 9999;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}
#modal.closeModal {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
}
#modal.transformScale {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.1);
}
#modalDarkBackground.modalDarkBackgroundOpen {
  z-index: 9998;
  opacity: 1;
}
#modalDarkBackground.modalDarkBackgroundClose {
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<button id="openModal">
  Open Modal
</button>

<div id="modalDarkBackground"></div>
<div id="modal">
  <h1>Error</h1>

  <p id="modalContent">
    You do not seem to have an Internet connection.
    Please check your connection.
  </p>

  <button id="closeModal">
    OK
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I converted your code into an executable snippet and also made the newly introduced css rules more specific in order to initially see at least the modal. But as it turns out, the modal gets displayed just once. One can not raise it again after it was closed the first time.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a `close` class while closing the modal, which can have different transition property - this property will use `cubic-berzier` to give the effect of expanding the modal, before completely contracting it. Then you can use `setTimeout` to remove the `close` class.

Here is the code:

```js
        const modal = document.getElementById("modal");
        const modalDarkBackground = document.getElementById("modalDarkBackground");

        document.getElementById("openModal").onclick = function () {
            modal.classList.add("open");
            modalDarkBackground.classList.add("open");
        }

        document.getElementById("closeModal").onclick = function () {
            modal.classList.add("close");
            modal.classList.remove("open");
            modalDarkBackground.classList.remove("open");
            setTimeout(function () { modal.classList.remove("close"); }, 500);
        }
```

```css
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        }

        #modalDarkBackground {
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100%;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            transition: all 0.5s;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            opacity: 0;
            z-index: -1;
        }

        #modalDarkBackground.open {
            opacity: 1;
            z-index: 9998;
        }

        #modal {
            width: 300px;
            position: fixed;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
            overflow: hidden;
            transition: all 0.5s;
            opacity: 0;
            background: #fff;
        }

        #modal.open {
            opacity: 1;
            z-index: 9999;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
        }

        #modal.close {
            opacity: 0;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
            transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.17, -0.16, 0.54, -0.42) !important;
        }

        #modal h1 {
            background: #E6E6E6;
            color: #ff0C0C;
            font-size: 20px;
            padding: 0.5em;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
        }

        #modal p {
            min-height: 70px;
            padding: 0.5em;
            color: #ff0C0C;
            font-weight: 400;
            font-size: 15px;
        }

        #modal button {
            display: block;
            width: 50%;
            padding: 0.5em 1em;
            background: #EDB44C;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 15px;
            margin: 0 auto 0.5em auto;
            border: 1px solid #BEBEBE;
            border-radius: 3px;
        }
```

```html
    <button id="openModal">
        Open Modal
    </button>

    <div id="modalDarkBackground"></div>
    <div id="modal">
        <h1>Error</h1>

        <p id="modalContent">
            You do not seem to have an Internet connection. Please check your connection.
        </p>

        <button id="closeModal">
            OK
        </button>
    </div>
```